# is there any Function to extract all the view modes for specific node?

Tags: 7, views, nodes

Is there any function which can give you all the types of view modes available for specific node? 
Also is there any direct(UI) way to check it ?

Is going to edit->manage_display the only way to get the view modes ?

Answer (score 0):

The code below will give me the list of view modes

```
$entity_info = entity_get_info('node');
$list_of_view_nodes = array_keys($entity_info['view modes']);
```